Time dependent perturbation theory validity and initial condition
This question concerns the validity of the perturbation theory formula that is so commonly found. The section to which I explicitly refer is section 18 of Shankar, 2nd edition (pg 473 on). Per usual we are assuming we can express the Hamiltonian
$\hat{H}(t) = \hat{H}^0 + \hat{H}^1(t) $
and use the assumption our solution takes the form
$|\Psi(t)\rangle = \sum_n d_n(t) e^{i {E_n}^0 t/\hbar}|n^0\rangle$.
On page 474, the typical derivation of the rate of change of the expansion coefficient $d_f(t)$ results in
$i\hbar \dot{d_f(t)} = \sum_n \langle{f^0}|H^1(t)|n^0\rangle^{i\omega_{fn}t}d_n(t)$
where the superscript $0$ indicates membership in the eigenbasis of the unperturbed Hamiltonian $\hat{H^0}$.
Not being a theorist, the message to me so far is that the original eigenbasis, while no longer stationary, remains complete and orthonormal, so we can project over that basis and find the coefficients. Fine.
We then make an assumption about the initial condition. We assume our perturbation turns on (becomes nonzero) at some time (t=0). So we say
$d_n(t=0) = \delta_{ni}$
and hence using the formula above,
$i\hbar\dot{d_f(t)} = \langle f^0|H^1(t)|i^0\rangle e^{i\omega_{fi}t}$
On page 475 Shankar then writes "the first-order calculation is reliable if $|d_f(t)| << 1$, $(f\neq i)$. If this condition is violated, our calculation becomes internally inconsistent, for we can no longer approximate $d_n(t)$ by $\delta_{ni}$".
I do not understand what is meant by "internally inconsistent." What is the word "internally" about? Why would the size of a coefficient make an initial condition wrong? I also don't understand why being of magnitude 1 throws things off. No matter the size of the inner product $\langle f^0|H^1(t)|i^0\rangle$, is it not true that we can expand over the original basis and find coefficients and thus completely represent the state?
Even more fundamentally,
what does it mean to say $d_n(t=0) = \delta_{ni}$? What does this say about the state of the system for times before the perturbation is turned on $t<0$.
Any help, or guidance is greatly appreciated.

$d_n(0)=\delta_{ni}$ means the system is in the eigenstate you are calling $i$ at the time you are calling $0$. More explicitly, it means that $d_i=1$ at $t=0$ and all other $d_n=0$ at $t=0$. This is also why it matters whether or not $d_f(t)<<1$. You want your correction to be small, meaning you want your coefficients that are not $d_i$ to be small compared to 1.

Thanks for the reply. But my question is more asking why we want the correction to be small. What about a non small correction makes the assumptions invalid?

The only assumption I see you mentioning is that the system is in state $i$ at $t=0$. Nothing makes this assumption invalid. Rather, the concern is mainly whether or not you can trust your perturbative results for $t>0$ if some $d_{n\neq i}$ is close to 1.

He's saying you can't make the approximation $d_{n}(t)\approx \delta_{ni}$. He's not saying you can't assume that $d_n(0)=\delta_{ni}$.

But why can you not trust perturbative results if the magnitude $d_n(t)$ gets close to 1?

I think you should reconsider time-dependent perturbation theory as a whole and not look just at the isolated first-order result. The points that you address are problems of using the first-order result as approximation for the true time-dependent coefficient, and it is the first-order approximation that becomes problematic when there is too much population transfer starting from a single state.
The coefficient is expanded in orders of the perturbation and has generally the  form
$$d_n(t) = \sum^\infty _{n=0} d^{(n)}_n(t)$$
where $n$ is the order of the expansion in the perturbation. The problems that you discuss are due to the following approximation
$$d_n(t) \approx  d^{(0)}_n(t) + d^{(1)}_n(t)$$
i.e. by truncating the expansion at first order. Now, when you use the initial condition $d_n(t_0)=1$, you will find that
$$d^{(0)}_n(t) = \textrm{const } = 1$$
and
$$
d^{(1)}_n(t) = 0.
$$
i.e. with an initial condition that $d_{m}(t_0)=\delta_{nm}$ your first order result predicts that this states coefficient will not change, it remains constant. Your first-order result is thus only a good approximation as long as this is true and conversely if all other coefficients remain small. Once this is no longer the case, you need to include higher order contributions, that will again introduce a time-dependency in your approximation for $d_n$ that includes terms that are proportional to the other coefficients. These terms are clearly important once the other coefficients grow.
The initial condition itself is of course perfectly valid but the truncated series is not a good approximation for all times. And you need to include higher order terms if you wish to make it valid again.
